# UPS Integration on 2.4.6 from non-US country

Tags: shipping, magento2.4.6, ups

Morning all,

I'm having some issues getting UPS set up on our Magento website. In all my years of Magento development, I've never worked with this carrier, probably because all of the clients are UK based. With this, I'm not familiar with the information I should be getting back.

On checkout, I'm getting "this shipping method is currently unavailable".

If I enable the log, I'm not getting any errors:

```
main.DEBUG: array (
 'request' => '{
"RateRequest": {
    "Request": {
        "TransactionReference": {
            "CustomerContext": "Rating and Service"
        }
    },
    "Shipment": {
        "Shipper": {
            "Name": "UPS",
            "ShipperNumber": "",
            "Address": {
                "AddressLine": [
                    "01"
                ],
                "City": "[City]",
                "StateProvinceCode": "[Code]",
                "PostalCode": "[Postcode]",
                "CountryCode": "GB"
            }
        },
        "ShipTo": {
            "Address": {
                "AddressLine": [
                    "01"
                ],
                "StateProvinceCode": "",
                "PostalCode": "",
                "CountryCode": "GB",
                "ResidentialAddressIndicator": "01"
            }
        },
        "ShipFrom": {
            "Address": {
                "AddressLine": [],
                "StateProvinceCode": "[Code from]",
                "PostalCode": "[Postcode from]",
                "CountryCode": "GB"
            }
        },
        "Package": [
            {
                "PackagingType": {
                    "Code": "00",
                    "Description": "Packaging"
                },
                "Dimensions": {
                    "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                        "Code": "IN",
                        "Description": "Inches"
                    },
                    "Length": "5",
                    "Width": "5",
                    "Height": "5"
                },
                "PackageWeight": {
                    "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                        "Code": "KGS"
                    },
                    "Weight": "149.8"
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }',
    'result' => '',
     ) [] []
```

Noting in the exception or php error log either, which is painful.

Interestingly, I've tried the correct credentials (user id and password) and the incorrect ones. Still, same results. Humph.

I'm using the United Parcel Service REST type.

Other points I've attended to after frustrated googling:

- I applied the patch discussed in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37534
- As far as I can tell, the XML mode was deprecated, so I cannot get an API key generated
- My shipping origin is correct
- All my products have weights
- I've tried regular UPS type, but it just times out.
- Tried Mode: Live/Development and Live Account: Yes/No.
- Shipping origins and destination types set correctly

I also installed the official UPS extension (https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/ups-shipping.html) which flat out breaks when I install it.

My next step is to try and upgrade to 2.4.6-p2, in the hope there's another patch I've missed.

Please can someone give me an idea as to what I could have missed? I'm leaning towards the actual UPS account being set up incorrectly, but as incorrect credentials give no error, I'm unsure that it's even connecting!

It doesn't help that (as usual) the documentation is very poor! There is documentation out there, but it doesn't go into detail what the account pre-requesits need to be. It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some consultation with the UK UPS team, it appears I'm using the wrong kind of plugin for this.

It turns out the extension at https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/ups-shipping.html did the job for me. I previously said this was non-functional, but after removing and re-installing, it works absolutely perfectly!